# Base64 cannot be resolved (Java 1.7)

Tags: java, apache-commons-codec

I have the following snippet and I have some unresolved classes - mainly, Base64

```
String auth = username + ":" + password; 
byte[] encodedAuth = Base64.encodeBase64(auth.getBytes(StandardCharsets.ISO_8859_1));
String authHeader = "Basic " + new String(encodedAuth);
request.setHeader(HttpHeaders.AUTHORIZATION, authHeader);
```

I've tried to import the commons-codec maven repository but in Eclipse it still says cannot resolve class:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>commons-codec</groupId>
    <artifactId>commons-codec</artifactId>
    <version>1.12</version>
</dependency>
```

We're kinda stuck for now using JDK7 which may be the issue. Is this Base64 class only available from Java 8? Otherwise, how do I import it into my application?

Comment: The standard `java.util.Base64` class is only available in java 8+. The reason you can't see the one from `commons-codec` is not your java version. Please check your project configuration

Comment: According to https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-codec/ this version of commons-codec requires Java 1.7 so should be fine(?)

Comment: Your code seems to compile with `commons-codec` 1.12. Do you have the right import ? `import org.apache.commons.codec.binary.Base64;`

Comment: That's it, I manually wrote out the import statement and it resolved. Strangely the commons-codec doesn't show in the Eclipse popup. I'm just running against a test environment at the moment, so might be something I need to keep an eye out for whether that library is being imported or not. Thanks for posting the proper package anyway.

Answer (score 1):

If you check the Javadoc, it clearly says that `Base64` is `Since 1.8`.

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Base64.html

Not sure about the `commons-codec` one, you must have something wrong in Eclipse (not suprised considering how crap its Maven integration is).

Comment: Yes, but that indicates that Base64 is included with Java 1.8, right? So how do versions prior to 8 import Base64 codecs if they are not available in the JDK? Also Mavan seems fine, it's only this repo that I'm having issues with. According to https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-codec/ it requires java 1.7, so should be OK(?)

Comment: Yes the commons-codec one should work. Not sure why it is not showing on your Eclipse IDE. On my IntelliJ it loads instantly.